# compile R package in R console using Rtools

Tags: r, package

To avoid the irregular parameter error caused by the directory including space and set workspace and tool path at once, I tried to compile R package in R console. My goal is compile the new version of "text2vec-0.4" which downloaded from https://github.com/dselivanov/text2vec/tree/0.4

```
setwd("E:/packbuild/")
builder <- "D:/Program Files/R/R-3.3.1/bin/x64/Rcmd.exe"
para <- "INSTALL --build"
packname <- "text2vec-0.4"
system(paste(shQuote(builder), para, packname, sep = " "), wait = FALSE)
```

When I run this program, it runs “successfully” no errors or warnings, but when I check the workspace"E:/packbuild/", there is no zip files generated and no new files installed in the R library. Rtools has completely installed in “D:/Rtools/” and its default path set has done.

- Does Rtools can’t call by a meta program like this?
- Or if we use command line, and don’t write directory of “Rcmd” into
  path, how to do is right?

Comment: Did you try to follow these instructions:
http://www.mathfinance.cn/how-to-create-an-R-package-in-windows/  ?
generally you should use `R CMD build` for building packages. Or just use `devtools::build` from R.

Comment: Yes, I read every materials I could found. And I discoverd the reason by myself. The error occurs because the location of Rtools is not default, but my customized directory. Even I had checked the setting in system path(D:\Rtools), "Rcmd" still call them in "C:\Rtools". And I don't know the reason. Can we keep Rtools in other directory than C and fix this problem? Thanks.